# SQL insert into existing table based on condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an existing table `vault` in my database, with some data in it. Now I need to add another column to it. It's a boolean `is_master` telling whether each vault is the "master" vault or not.

The condition whether the vault is master or not can be calculated based on the current values.

- **IF** `vault.name` = "Master" --> `is_master = true`
- **ELSE** --> `is_master = false`

I need an SQL script that will run through all my existing vaults in the database and calculate the new `is_master` column based on the `name` column.

I don't know exactly how to write such condition in SQL, it should probably be something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE vault
ADD COLUMN is_master BOOLEAN NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO vault (id, created_at, updated_at, company_name, country, is_master)
SELECT id, created_at, updated_at, company_name, country, true // false if not "Master"
FROM vault
WHERE vault.name = 'Master';
```

Could someone help me out with the query?

Comment: You're looking for an `UPDATE` query, not an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a boolean:

```
ALTER TABLE vault ADD COLUMN is_master BOOLEAN NOT NULL;

UPDATE value
    SET is_master = (name = 'Master');
```

EDIT:

To handle `NULL` values for master:

```
UPDATE value
    SET is_master = (name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'Master');
```

Comment: I seem to be getting some null constraint errors.

ERROR: column \"is_master\" contains null values